# Developer disk-image for Xcode 10.3

Tags: ios, xcode, diskimage

I recently - and inadvertently - updated the iPad I use to test my apps to iOS 13.1.3.

I haven't made the step up to Catalina on my Mac due to having rather a lot of software that isn't 64-bit, eg Office for Mac, and hence I'm still using Xcode 10.3.

The first time I ran my app, Xcode told me that it couldn't find the disk image and perhaps it wasn't support in this version of Xcode.  A little bit of digging pointed the finger at the upgrade, and after many futile attempts, I then discovered that Apple have now stopped signing the certificate for 12.4.1 and so I couldn't downgrade.

Much searching and pulling of hair later, I managed to find, via GitHub, a Developer Disk-Image for iOS 13.1 (17A844), and copied it to the correct folder, seemingly solving the issue as the app now runs.

Unfortunately, although the app as a whole runs, the UISteppers refuse to have their values set programmatically and always revert to the value set in the Storyboard.  Run the app on the simulator and everything is hunky-dory (as this still runs iOS 12.4), but run it on my actual iPad and the values refused to be changed.

Whilst, Apple are hardly likely to solve this problem due to wanting me to upgrade, does anyone know of a work-around of any sort?  Does a disk-image for 13.1.3 exist? (I've searched but don't seem to be able to find one on-line.) Or am I essentially being forced to upgrade to Xcode 11, Catalina and spend all the extra money to replace my old software?

Comment: Xcode 11 runs in macOS 10.14.4 and later so you do not need Catalina (10.15).

Comment: Many thanks RMaddy - I'm a little new to all this and hence that hadn't even occurred to me.  I now have everything running, albeit with slightly different graphics, but the UISteppers are behaving.  Thanks again.